# Maven repository : Browsing for this directory has been disabled

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to download dependencies using Maven but Maven is not downloading any jars from the central repository which means i have to manually install them which is a pain

I can telnet from my computer to the central repository using `telnet repo.maven.apache.org 80` but when i use a browser to access the repository `http://repo.maven.apache.org/` i am getting the following webpage

```
Browsing for this directory has been disabled.

View this directory's contents on http://search.maven.org instead.

Find out more about The Central Repository.
```

I have tried adding the following to my pom but this has not worked either

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>              
              <id>central</id>
              <name>Central</name>
              <url>http://search.maven.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Has anyone else come across this and if so how did you resolve this?

EDIT : pom.xml

Just to note, i have set this exact same project with all the same version of maven on other environments but just the one i am working on now seems to not be able to download the jars from the central repository

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <name>ProjectName</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>        
<!--        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version> -->
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.1.1</version> -->
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tiles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudbees.thirdparty</groupId>
            <artifactId>vijava</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.31.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.01</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>3.9</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    </exclusion>        
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.ga</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>       

        <!-- Spring Security --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>               

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you try `maven compile` ? Maven will downloand dependencies (and plugins and stuff) first time he will needs it

Comment: could you post whole `pom.xml` and your `settings.xml` file. If you have any settings.xml it should be under `$USER_HOME/.m2/settings.xml`

Comment: i do not have any settings.xml... posting pom.xml now

Comment: @Antoniossss : i have tried maven compile bit it errors out with 'could not resolve dependencies for project...'

Comment: Don't try to configured the defaults in your pom file (Maven Central is configured already in Maven) so no need to do this separately.

Answer (score 1):

i FINALLY found the issue. I am using Windows 8 with JRE 6 and 7 installed. In my development environment i am using JRE 7.

Im not sure about the specifics but it looks like the JRE was trying to use IPv6. I disabled this and set it to use IPv4 using the below command and it resolved everything

cmd : `setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Answer (score 0):

The browser behavior is expected. Web browsers are prohibited to browse the root directory and lot of large subdirectories (org/com/net).

However, if you need to browse the repo, deeper points can be browsed: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache

Note the **repo1**, *you should always be using the domain name, `repo1.maven.org`*.

UPDATE: looking at your `pom.xml`, seems you didn't replace standard info with your project info:

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>  // missing
<artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>  // missing
<name>ProjectName</name>      // missing
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Comment: ok, did not know that you could not browse to this. but do you have any idea so why Maven cannot download the jars from here so if i can telnet into it from my computer?

Comment: i have tried the link you provided and i could access that. i have tried repo1.maven.org in my repository tag but still not luck

Comment: i have changed the groupId, artifactId and name tags when i uploaded the pom (for security reasons) but the rest of the pom is the exact same... i have used this pom in other environments i have set up and everything worked fine, just not working on the current environment and i have changed nothing which is what is confusing me

Comment: weird... have you downloaded and installed maven without issues?

Comment: i think so, i done the same think i have always done... download maven. added environment variables for maven 'MAVEN_HOME' and 'M2_HOME' and add update the 'Path' variable with the maven \bin directory and this usually works... i have tried 'mvn -version' on the cmd and it works which should mean maven is set up correctly